# Запуск таймера при переходе в другую Activity

Tags: java, android-studio, countdowntimer

Имеется следующий код

```
new CountDownTimer(mfuture, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                moneyview.setText(mymoney + " ");
                moneytosecondView.setText(moneytosecond + " /sec");
                mfuture += 1000;
            }
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        }.start();
```

, находящийся в onCreate(). Это - таймер, через который я каждую секунду обновляю TextView в моей MainActivity.
Проблема заключается в том, что если я перехожу в другую Activity а потом возвращаюсь в предыдущую, запускается второй таймер, чего мне не нужно, чего мне не нужно, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить

Comment: На мой взгляд: самый адекватный способ, отделить таймер от активити, сделать его синглтоном для всего приложения и в нужных активити подписываться на изменения в этом таймере используя liveData например.

Comment: @Pentiux только не синглтон, а ViewModel будет уместнее

Comment: @pavlofff `the ViewModel exists from when you first request a ViewModel until the activity is finished and destroyed.` и  `If the Activity is not going to be recreated then the ViewModel will have the onCleared() method called where it can clean up any data it needs to before being destroyed.` Если мы переходим из одной активти в другое, разве не будет уничтожаться и ViewModel созданная в предыдущем активити?

Comment: @Pentiux вообще ViewModel будет уничтожена только после полного уничтожения активити, но да, ненулевая вероятность, что это произойдет при переходе на другую активити есть. Я что то подумал о одной и той же активити, невнимательно прочитал